# Передача значений из checkbox в функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

уважаемые коллеги. Я только недавно начал осваивать js и jquery, и в процессе написания одного скрипта для расчётчика возникла проблема.
Есть html таблица с checkbox, при нажатии на которые, их value динамически передаются в массив. Далее с элементами массива происходит математика и результаты записываются в нужные ячейки таблицы html. Также, необходимо что бы при нажатии на чекбокс передовались атрибуты id и name, т.к по моей задумке в них необходимо внести название, которое также будет выводиться в соответсвующую ячейку таблицы и один операнд для расчёта, результат которого также выводиться. Вопрос в том, если механики позволяющие подобные операции, как передача других атрибутов кроме value, и если нет то может идею подкинете как бы это реализовать. Я пыталься сделать это по аналогии с value и записью в массив, но на выходе получалось что, в массив записывается только одно и тоже name. Сейчас вот в таком виде представлено (и конечно не работает).

```
   var checks = $("input:checkbox");
   $("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
   var nameArr = new Array();
   for (var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++) {
   var checkboxies = checks[i];
   if ($(checkboxies).prop('checked')) {
   nameArr[nameArr.length] = $(checkboxies).attr('name');
     }
 }

 showSysName(nameArr);
 });

 var showSysName = function(array) {
 var NameOne = " ";
 var NameTwo = " ";
 var NameThree = " ";
 var NameFour = " ";
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 NameOne = nameArr.slice(0,1);
 NameTwo = nameArr.slice(1,2);
 NameThree = nameArr.slice(2,3);
 NameFour = nameArr.slice(3,4);
 }

$(".nameOne").html(NameOne);
$(".nameTwo").html(NameTwo);
$(".nameThree").html(NameThree);
$(".nameFour").html(NameFour);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Одно и то же значение у вас из-за строчки:

```
nameArr[nameArr.length] = $(checkboxies).attr('name');
```

Используйте для добавления в массив:

```
nameArr.push(element);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var arr = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
      arr.push($(this).attr('name'));
    } else {
      let idx = arr.indexOf($(this).attr('name'));
      arr.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    
    console.log(arr.join(', '));
  });
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='chk1' name='chk_name1' value='1' />1
<input type='checkbox' id='chk2' name='chk_name2' value='2' />2
<input type='checkbox' id='chk3' name='chk_name3' value='3' />3
```

Вообще вариантов для передачи много:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='chk1' name='chk_name1' value='1' />1
<input type='checkbox' id='chk2' name='chk_name2' value='2' />2
<input type='checkbox' id='chk3' name='chk_name3' value='3' />3
```

Comment: Не вполоне уверен почему, в процессе моих попыток реализовать конструкцию 'nameArr.push', в массив начали добавляться элементы по 2 раза. Я убрал данную конструкцию, слегка подредактировав код переписав обе функции в одну, и в всё заработало. Тем не менее, большое спасибо!

Comment: @CuteguyCorpse, дополнил ответ примером с push. Не совсем понятно в чем у вас затык. Чтобы понять проблему нужен полный код, не понятно например что такое boxes..